# Parse href out of html document and evaluating by xpath returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, html, parsing, xpath

I am going to parse URLs in specific location of one website. For this purpose I wrote a simple program in Java. But this program returns null pointer exception. It seems that `getNameItem("href")` returns null. I am suspicious about wrong way of using getNameItem to extract URLs inside "href" tag.

```
DocumentBuilder b = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = b.parse(new FileInputStream("clean.html"));

//Evaluate XPath against Document itself
javax.xml.xpath.XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate(".//*[@class='r_news_box']",
        doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) {
    Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    System.out.println(e.getAttributes().getNamedItem("href").getTextContent());
}
```

P.S: here is one of the nodes that should be selected by this xpath:

```
<div class="r_news_box">
<a class="picLink" target="_blank" href="/fa/news/427583/test">
<img class="r_news_img" width="50" height="65" src="/files/fa/news/1393/5/29/411217_553.jpg" alt="test"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly because not all nodes selected has `href` attribute. You may want to change your XPath to make sure only elements having `href` attribute are returned :

```
.//*[@class='r_news_box' and @href]
```

**UPDATE :**

According to your update, `href` is the attribute of `<a>` node within an element having `class` attribute equals `r_news_box`, so here is corrected XPath :

```
.//*[@class='r_news_box']/a[@href]
```

Comment: That simply means there is no node that has such  class and href attribute... post the node you want to select so we can help to correct the xpath

Comment: Please check the main question, I added one sample node.

Answer (score 0):

Writing an html parser with XML Parser Librarys is not a good idea. Most html sites are not valid xml documents. You can better use a html parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). It is really easy to use and self explained. Here is an [example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links).

Comment: I already cleaned HTML to xml with HTMLCleaner. So the clean.html is actually a clean xml document.